# How to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt[n]{x+\frac{1}{x}}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$ for $n\geq 2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Q) **How to integrate $$\int \frac{\sqrt[n]{x+\frac{1}{x}}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$$ for $n\geq 2$?**

Ans) **My Approach :**

When I was in Class $XIITh$ I learnt how to integrate $$\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{x+\frac{1}{x}}dx$$ . To Integrate $$\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{x+\frac{1}{x}}dx$$ we substitute $(x+\frac{1}{x})=t$ and then $(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}})dx=dt$ . Therefore we can say that

$$\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{x+\frac{1}{x}}dx=\ln|x+\frac{1}{x}|+C$$

Similarly we can also integrate:

$$\int \frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$$ .

Let $$I=\int \frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$$

$$\implies I=\int \frac{x^{3}+x}{x^{2}-1}dx$$

$$\implies I=\int \frac{x(x^{2}-1)+2x}{x^{2}-1}dx$$

$$\implies I=\int (x+\frac{2x}{x^{2}-1})dx$$

$$\implies I= \frac{x^{2}}{2}+\ln|x^{2}-1|+C$$

**My doubt :**

I am facing problem in integrating

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$$

and $$\int \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+\frac{1}{x}}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$$

I have also searched the solutions in Wolfram Alpha but I have not understood the way of solution.

For the integral $$\int\frac{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$$ , as far as I have understood it is giving answer in terms of hypergeometric functions.

And for the integral $$\int\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+\frac{1}{x}}}{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}dx$$ Wolfram Alpha is not giving answer in terms of standard mathematical functions.

**Please help me out with this integral.**

Comment: For $n=2$ is special function **AppellF1**.

Comment: Why do you expect that there is a closed form solution? Not all integrals can be expressed in closed form. Only Series solution: $\int \frac{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/n}}{1-\frac{1}{x^2}} \, dx=-\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{n x^{1-2 m} \left(\frac{1}{x}+x\right)^{1/n}
   \left(1+x^2\right) \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2} \left(3-2 m+\frac{1}{n}\right);\frac{3}{2}-m-\frac{1}{2 n};-x^2\right)}{1+(-1+2 m) n}+C$

Answer (score -2):

Let $u(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, then $$\int  \frac{(x + u)^{1/n}}{1 - u^2} dx$$

Let $(x + u) = (1 - u^2)$, and then  $x = 1 - u - u^2$ so
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{u \pm \sqrt{ 5u^2}}{2}\\
  &= \frac{u + |u|\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align}
but $u=1/x$ hence

$$2x = \frac{1}{x} + \left|\frac{1}{x}\right|\sqrt{5}$$
by composition.

That means, in order for us to try and cancel the numerator and denominator— there is a very specific value for $x$ for that to be possible (it is not divisible for all values of $x$). Plus, I think I messed up the quadratic, but the idea is there.

So you can’t divide these terms via this form of factorization.

1. You can try a polynomial expansion:
   $$(a + b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i} a^ib^{n-i} $$
   then try to isolate $(a + b)$ — which shouldn’t work, because there is no equation for factorizing $n$-degree polynomial expansions. I think.
2. $\tan(a + b)$ has a similar form. You can try and find a substitution, but it’ll be hard:
   $$\tan(a + b) = \frac{\tan(a) + \tan(b)}{1 - \tan(a)\tan(b)}$$

So, let $\tan(a + b) = \tan\left(F(x,u) + G(x,u)\right)$, but idk what we should define for $F$ and $G$, so that we get a clean matching expression.

Also, you still have to consider the $n$-root part of the equation.

You can try Partial Fraction Decomposition. It might be easier. Consult a professional— that is not something I know how to do very well.

I don’t think there is a solution. Even if there is, I don't think it looks important. You can try approximating the solution with some Optimization expression—
I recommend not pursuing this problem if you know there is no solution.

Comment: Why is there no $\ln$ term once you substitute?

Comment: I didn’t follow through with the integration itself, (which might result in an ln)— I attempted to simplify the integrand, which is the substitution you see, but couldn’t get any terms to cancel. 

So, I made some suggestions instead. My response to the problem, was just me trying to help. I don’t think there is a solution, but I could be wrong (integrating isn’t my strength), so I tried to offer suggestions, post-algebra.

Thank you to @cjferes, for formatting everything. That looks incredible (even if it’s just scratchwork).